# How to put a message back in the queue using latest SpringBoot and ActiveMQ classic

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling, activemq-classic

I am designing a simple system where the flow is going to be like this:

`Message Producer Microservice --> Active MQ --> Message Consumer Microservice --> Mongo DB`

I need to design a queuing strategy in a way so that if MongoDB is down, I should not lose the message (because Message consumer will dequeue the message).

My consumer is written like this:

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "Consumer.myconsumer.VirtualTopic.Tracking")
    public void onReceiveFromQueueConsumer2(TrackingRequest trackingRequest) {
        log.debug("Received tracking request from the queue by consumer 2");
        log.debug(trackingRequest.toString());
    }
```

How do you provide client acknowledgement?

Comment: @JustinBertram I have updated the question for better clarity. Question is that if MongoDB is down, how can we process the same message after may be several hours?

Answer (score 0):

You can use client acknowledge mode from your "Message Consumer Microservice." Since you're using a Spring `JmsListener` you can define the listener container using the [`containerFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html#containerFactory--) and then you can set the mode you want on your listener container using `sessionAcknowledgeMode`. See [the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html) for more details on what ack mode you might want to use here.

From the perspective of the ActiveMQ client you can configure redelivery semantics however you like in case of a failure. See the [ActiveMQ documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy) for more about that.

Comment: Hi, I have edited this question to understand how to get client acknowledgment if my consumer is written using @JMSListener. Thanks.

Comment: I update my answer to address the changes in your question. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I was able to solve this dilemma, here is what your config should be like (thanks to Justin for his valuable inputs):

```
    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(userName);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(password);
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy());
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerCF = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        listenerCF.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        listenerCF.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        listenerCF.setSessionTransacted(true);
        return listenerCF;
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    public RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy() {
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(600000L); //keep trying every 10 minutes
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(-1); //Keep trying till its successfully inserted
        return redeliveryPolicy;
    }
```

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as such to help others who may have this same question in the future. Thanks!